# Save PDF in StringIO object with pypdf

Tags: python, pypdf

How can save a PDF in RAM using pypdf? I'm trying using `write()` to save the PDF into a StringIO object. I've seen [something like that](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/16/pypdf-how-to-write-a-pdf-to-memory/) from when pypdf was pyPdf. But it doesn't work anymore.

In the documentation it seems like current `write()` only accepts routes, not StringIO objects, like the former implementation.

This is what I'm trying to do to test what I need:

```
import pypdf
from io import StringIO 

with open('route_to_pdf.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(file)
    first_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
    file_in_ram = StringIO()
    pdf_writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()
    pdf_writer.add_page(first_page)
    pdf_writer.write(file_in_ram)
```

`write()` raises a TypeError because it's expecting a string or something like that:

```
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Comment: Do you want `io.BytesIO()` rather than `io.StringIO()` given you are writing a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BytesIO` to load binary data. Remember that it is designed to support file descriptor protocol... so don't forget to call `seek` at the right position before accessing its content!

```
import pypdf
from io import BytesIO


path = # path to pdf

with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(file)
    
    first_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
    file_in_ram = BytesIO()

    pdf_writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

    pdf_writer.add_page(first_page)
    pdf_writer.write(file_in_ram)

    # process the byte-object
    file_in_ram.seek(0)  # move at the start of the file<----- !!!
    print(file_in_ram.read())

    file_in_ram.close()
```

Notes on `BytesIO`:

- if you initialize `BytesIO(bdata)` there is no need to call explicitly the `seek` method. Instead if you add your data with `write` you need to call it.
- as every descriptor it should also be closed with `close` or use it inside context manager initialization (`with`).